# Automatic "Distractor Generation" for Multiple Choice Questions using Machine Learning

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I have three columns in my train dataset - Question, Answer and Distractor.

As we know, MCQ has a question and 4 options. Out of that 1 answer is correct and other 3 are distractor.

I have two columns in my test set - Question and Answer. And I need to predict Distractor.

Please suggest how to deal with the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your goal is? For a pair of a question and a correct answer, you want to automatically generate a distractor?

Comment: Yes, exactly.

I have a pair of question and correct answer. And I need to generated 3 distractor from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a machine-learning solution: this is a sequence-to-sequence learning problem. However, sequence-to-sequence learning requires large amounts of training data and probably will not work well unless you have hundreds of thousands of examples.

The question and answer separated by a special token will be the input and the distractor answers will the output. You can use something like [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py), [JoyeNMT](https://github.com/joeynmt/joeynmt), [Marian](https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian) or whatever other tools for seq2seq you will find.